# Fix branch when upstream has changed

Tags: git

I am working on a branch `feature-b` that branched from `feature-a`. `feature-a` has had some commits squashed and merged and then `git push -f` to the remote, so I am unsure how to save my `feature-b`.

The histories looked like this:

```
A - B - C (feature-a) 
     \
      D (feature-b)
```

and now look like this:

```
A' (feature-a `after squash`)
 \
  ?
   \
    D (feature-b)
```

The change in D is not huge, but I'm more interested in how to reconcile this situation given that it has happened.

I know to avoid `git push -f` and squashing when that history has been committed. Is there a way to clean up commits if I have branched off my own feature branch?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do it:

```
git rebase --onto origin/feature-a old-feature-a-tip feature-b
```

What you are telling git is to rebase the revisions that belong to feature-b *discarding* all the revisions related to the *old* feature-a (those that belong to the old feature.... say you had already set up a local branch on the old feature A and that branch already had some some changes that were not included in your feature B? That doesn't matter, gt will discard anything on the history of old-feature-a so it could be the last revision belonging to feature-a that also belong to the current history of feature-b), and place them **on top** of the new feature-a.

Answer (score -1):

I would try:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout feature-b
$ git rebase feature-a
```

if no conflicts, this should end with the `?` commits gone, and the `D` commit as a direct child of `A'`

Comment: As I just told Daniel, this is not good because git will _also_ try to rebase the revisions of feature-a as they are in the history of feature-b... and before you say "that's not a problem because they would fail to be rebased and you can skip them", let me tell you that the new feature-a can be very different from the old feature-a and so if you are moving a different branch, there's no point in moving a separate branch along with it (it's not yours, not your responsibility, don't try).

Comment: Oh... and also, after fetching, you would need to move feature-a (local) to new position of feature-a (remote) so that this works.... anyway, the previous comment still overrides the answer.